# mlr: Create ensemble from resampling

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr

I'm playing around with the `mlr` package and `xgboost`.
My idea is to create a bunch of slightly different models by resampling with a `FeatureWrapper` and a `TuneWrapper`.
After the resampling is done, I would like to continue tuning each model, then combine them into an ensemble.

The problem is that the resampling process leaves me with trained models, not `mlr` learners:

```
# This code chunk does the trick for Step 1
my_learner <- 
  makeLearner(
    "classif.xgboost", 
    my_task, 
    target = "y", 
    positive = 1
  ) %>%
  makeFilterWrapper(., fw.method = "auc", fw.abs = 5) %>%
  makeTuneWrapper(.,
    task = my_task,
    resampling = makeResampleDesc("CV", iter = 5),
    control = makeTuneControlIrace(maxExperiments = 200L),
    par.set = my_par_set,
    measures = auc
  )

  r <- resample(
    learner = my_learner,
    resampling = makeResampleDesc("CV", iter = 10),
    models = T,
    extract = getTuneResult,
    measures = auc
  )
```

`r` contains everything I need to know with respect to what features were selected for each model, and what tuning parameters it ended up using.

My question:

How can I easily create learner objects that represent each model's feature selection? I can find the features for each model through `sapply(r$models, getFilteredFeatures)`, but are there any helper functions that will use this information to define a list of learners?

Answer (score 0):

I can just use the bagging functionalities built into `mlr` instead of messing around with resampling:

https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/bagging.html

Comment: That is a good idea but the bootstrap generated from bagging is not the same as the CV splits.